# why does Haskell require numbers to be disambiguated for printf but not for show?

Tags: haskell, types, printf, type-signature, hindley-milner

Why is `printf "%d\n" 3` ambiguous but not `show 3`? Could the `printf` module be rewritten to provide automatic disambiguation? Presumably something like `show` must be done at the lower levels of `printf` ... or is there some crucial difference between `printf` and `show` that requires the disambiguation of numbers?

If `printf` **can** be rewritten to automatically handle numbers without explicit disambiguation, then what is `show` doing right? How does `show` turn numbers into strings without the `:: Int` disambiguation of `printf`?

Here is the correct operation of `show` (without any disambiguation) and also the correct operation of `printf` (with the disambiguation):

```
$ cat printStrLnShow3
import Text.Printf
main = putStrLn (show 3)
$ runghc printStrLnShow3
3
$ cat printfWithInt3
import Text.Printf
main = printf "%d\n" (3 :: Int)
$ runghc printfWithInt3
3
```

Here is the *ambiguous variable* error when `printf` does **not** disambiguate the number:

```
$ cat printfWithAmbiguous3
import Text.Printf
main = printf "%d\n" 3
$ runghc printfWithAmbiguous3

printfWithAmbiguous3:2:8:
    No instance for (PrintfArg a0) arising from a use of `printf'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance [safe] PrintfArg Char -- Defined in `Text.Printf'
      instance [safe] PrintfArg Double -- Defined in `Text.Printf'
      instance [safe] PrintfArg Float -- Defined in `Text.Printf'
      ...plus 12 others
    In the expression: printf "%d" 3
    In an equation for `main': main = printf "%d" 3

printfWithAmbiguous3:2:22:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `3'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus 11 others
    In the second argument of `printf', namely `3'
    In the expression: printf "%d" 3
    In an equation for `main': main = printf "%d" 3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a quirk of the defaulting rules, which explicitly say that you may default a typeclass-polymorphic value to something monomorphic only when there are a fixed set of classes in the context:

> In situations where an ambiguous type is discovered, an ambiguous type variable, `v`, is defaultable if:
>
> - `v` appears only in constraints of the form `C v`, where `C` is a class, and
> - at least one of these classes is a numeric class, (that is, `Num` or a subclass of `Num`), and
> - all of these classes are defined in the `Prelude` or a standard library (Figures 6.2–6.3 show the numeric classes, and Figure 6.1 shows the classes defined in the `Prelude`.)
>
> Each defaultable variable is replaced by the first type in the default list that is an instance of all the ambiguous variable’s classes. It is a static error if no such type is found.

([Section 4.3.4](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-750004.3) of the Report.) The troubling one here is bullet point 3, because the `PrintfArg a` constraint on the type of `3 :: (Num a, PrintfArg a) => a` mentions the class `PrintfArg` which is not in the `Prelude`.

GHC offers the `ExtendedDefaultRules` pragma to relax these rules, as described in [the manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--XExtendedDefaultRules):

> Find all the unsolved constraints. Then:
>
> - Find those that are of form `(C a)` where `a` is a type variable, and partition those constraints into groups that share a common type variable `a`.
> - Keep only the groups in which at least one of the classes is an interactive class (defined below).
> - Now, for each remaining group G, try each type *ty* from the default-type list in turn; if setting `a` = *ty* would allow the constraints in G to be completely solved. If so, default `a` to *ty*.
> - The unit type `()` and the list type `[]` are added to the start of the standard list of types which are tried when doing type defaulting.
>
> Note that any multi-parameter constraints `(D a b)` or `(D [a] Int)` do not participate in the process (either to help or to hinder); but they must of course be soluble once the defaulting process is complete.

And indeed, turning on this pragma makes your file work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
import Text.Printf
main = printf "%d\n" 3
```

Comment: Good clarification. So in a nutshell, code in Prelude is privileged. And one effect of ExtendedDefaultRules is the granting of extra privileges to my external code.